# IP camera simulation using python and opencv

Tags: python, opencv, camera, opencv3.0, ip-camera

I have a use-case in which I am **simulating IP camera** using **python** and **opencv**.

I am playing video using opencv and **sending the bytes of the frame to an application** which is streaming it at a port 8080.

**The problem is** as soon as the video gets finished, I have nothing to send to the application which is streaming this `fake simulated camera` at port 8080, so the `application` takes it as timeout and stops working.

**My question is**, how can I send some `fake bytes` lets days a black screen noise just to **keep alive my application** which is listening to my face simulated camera at 8080?

**Edit 1:** Adding code

**app.py**

```
from camera import VideoCamera
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

def gen(camera):
    while True:
        try:
            frame = camera.get_frame()
        except Exception:
            print("Video is finished or empty")
            #return None
            frame = camera.get_heartbeat()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen(VideoCamera()),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**camera.py**

```
import cv2

class VideoCamera(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # Using OpenCV to capture from device 0. If you have trouble capturing
        # from a webcam, comment the line below out and use a video file
        # instead.
        #self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        # If you decide to use video.mp4, you must have this file in the folder
        # as the main.py.
        # self.video = cv2.VideoCapture('suits_hd.mp4') 
        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture('nature.mp4')

    def __del__(self):
        self.video.release()

    def get_frame(self):
        success, image = self.video.read()
        # We are using Motion JPEG, but OpenCV defaults to capture raw images,
        # so we must encode it into JPEG in order to correctly display the
        # video stream.
        ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)
        return jpeg.tobytes()

    def get_heartbeat(self):
        # jpeg = cv2.imread('noise-black.jpg')
        image = cv2.imread('noise-green.jpg')
        ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)
        return jpeg.tobytes()
```

Comment: If you show your code that sends the *"normal"* bytes, it should become clear how to send fake bytes.

Comment: Added code, please have a look

Comment: So, when you init the VideoCamera, get the width and height of the video frames in the file and remember them. Then, if `self.video.read()` fails, just use `numpy` to create a random array the same size as a video frame and `imencode()` and send that.

Comment: ` just use numpy to create a random array the same size as a video frame and imencode() and send that`, how to do this?

Comment: `image = np.random.randint(0,256,(320,240,3), dtype=np.uint8)` for a 320x240 frame in colour

Comment: thanks, how to decide color lets say green

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176486/discussion-between-codex-and-mark-setchell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, when you init the VideoCamera, get the width and height of the video frames in the file and remember them. Then, if `self.video.read()` fails, just use `numpy` to create a random array the same size as a video frame and `imencode()` and send that.

Make a random green-ish frame with:

```
import numpy as np

# Make the Green channel out of intensities in range 200-255
G=np.random.randint(200,256,(320,240,1), dtype=np.uint8)
# Make Red and Blue channel out of intensities in range 0-49
X=np.random.randint(0,50,(320,240,1), dtype=np.uint8)
# Merge into a 3-channel image, use BGR order with OpenCV - although it won't matter because G is in the middle in both!
image=np.concatenate((X,G,X),axis=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to recognize  the end of the video file, you could just send a black image, which you could read from file.
`cv2.imread('black.jpg')`and then send this one through the socket.

Comment: For color green in the np array you'd need  to generate the values with a coresponding rgb code.

Comment: I did this but the application reads a real ip camera (in my case reading a simulated fake ip camera) exit when feeded black image for more than 4 second. Green image works though.